# boost_python3 and boost_numpy3 to reference to both Python3 as well as Python2

Tags: boost

I build boost with Python 3 (3.6.1) but I see some issue

> ldd boost/v1.63.0p1/lib/libboost_numpy3.so.1.63.0

libboost_python.so.1.63.0 => not found

My concern is with this line:

libboost_python.so.1.63.0 => not found

I would expect to be compiled against

libboost_python3.so.1.63.0 => /boost/v1.63.0p1/lib/libboost_python3.so.1.63.0

I used the following configuration to compile it with  python 3

## Configure specific Python version.(user-config.jam)

using python : 3.6 : python/v3.6.1/bin/python3 : python/v3.6.1/include/python3.6m : python/v3.6.1/lib ;

Here are the commands I used to build this:

1- ./bootstrap.sh --prefix=/tools/boost --with-python=/python/v3.6.1/bin/python3 --with-python-version=3.6 --with-python-root=/python/v3.6.1

2- ./b2 install --config=user-config.jam

I am trying to build boost 1.63.0

Comment: Can someone please help me on this ?

Answer (score 0):

Fixed required a small change on code “boost_1_63_0/libs/python/build/Jamfile” at line 143

- boost_python
- [ cond $(is-py3) : boost_python3 : boost_python ]